# Using array_combine in a foreach loop to convert multiple arrays into a single array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying array_combine to convert all these arrays into a single array with the unique value.

```
$arr_ch_no = array();
        $arr_ch_no[] = "'***0***'";
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT ship_name,voy_no from tb_veh_data_entry WHERE (ETAQ > '".date("Y-m-d")."' or (ETAQ <> '0000-00-00' and stock = 0 and stock_sale_date = '0000-00-00')) and (user_id = 'UI08-00000063' or user_id = 'UI09-00000111') and stock_country = 58 and ((buyer in ('6371','2509','2535') and arica = 0 ) or arica=4)  group by ship_name,voy_no  ");
        while($row_no = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $str_no_ch = selFieldCon("tb_veh_data_entry","GROUP_CONCAT(frame_no)"," ship_name = '".$row_no['ship_name']."' and voy_no = '".$row_no['voy_no']."'   and (user_id = 'UI08-00000063' or user_id = 'UI09-00000111') and stock_country = 58   and ((buyer in ('6371','2509','2535') and arica = 0 ) or arica=4) and ETAQ <> '0000-00-00' ".$this->condition."");
            $arr_no_ch = array();
            $arr_no_ch = explode(",",$str_no_ch);
            if($str_no_ch != '')
            foreach($arr_no_ch as $val)
                $arr_ch_no[] = "'".$val."'";
        }
```

This query use for **foreach loop**

```
$sql    =    "SELECT * FROM tb_veh_data_entry WHERE 1 ".$this->condition." ";
```

I am trying this inside foreach.

```
foreach loop //start

array_unique(array_combine($arr_ch_no));
```

How can I convert it into a single array inside foreach.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => '***0***'
        [1] => 'NCP100-0027131'
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => '***0***'
        [1] => 'NCP100-0027131'
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => '***0***'
        [1] => 'NCP100-0027131'
    )
```

But I do not get anything.

Comment: is that your actual code?

Comment: Please define the steps you undertake to convert multiple arrays into one array, what is the intended result?

Comment: @billynoah updated.

Comment: sorry but your code makes no sense.  what is `foreach loop` supposed to do?  why are you initializing the array, adding something to it and then initializing it again? then you create an array and iterate over it, adding it's own values again?!  what are you trying to do

Comment: @billynoah updated.

Comment: @billynoah I need above array inside foreach loop as an single array.

Answer (score -1):

this is not good solution. hope it can help you.

```
$data1 = array_column($array, 0, 1);
$data2 = array_column($array, 1, 0);

$data1Length = count($data1);
$data2Length = count($data2);

$result = [];
if($data1Length > $data2Length) {
    foreach($data1Length as $k => $v) {
        $result[] = [$v, $k];
    }
} else {
    foreach($data1Length as $k => $v) {
        $result[] = [$k, $v];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please See this first: [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) and [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)